# Oracle Transparent Gateway 10g to Connect to SQL Server 2012

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, gateways

I'm going to upgrade an old application using SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012, an Oracle Server transfer data to this application using the Oracle Transparent Gateway daily.
I have a new server in which I installed SQL Server 2012 for testing with all the data and users from the old SQL Server 2000, just exactly.

I'm performing initial tests, and when I change my configuration to test connections to the new SQL Server 2012, I get the error:

```
SQL> Desc SOMETABLE@SOMEDBLINK;
ERROR:
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Transparent gateway for MSSQL]DRV_InitTdp: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'correctlyconfigureduser'. (SQL State: 00000; SQL
Code: 18456)
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from SOMEDBLINK
```

In the logs I found this:

```
2012-10-31 18:41:21.673: [  OCRRAW][9132]proprinit: Could not open raw device 
2012-10-31 18:41:21.673: [ default][9132]a_init:7!: Backend init unsuccessful : [33]
2012-10-31 18:41:21.688: [ CSSCLNT][9132]clsssinit: error(33 ) in OCR initialization
```

I already logged in with the user involved and the user and password are fine. They are a copy of the old database anyway.

I'm wondering if may be this Oracle Transparent Gateway 10g (10.2) is just too old to connect to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when the dblink was created the user and password were not entered within quotes.
Once recreated the dblinks everything worked fine.